# Laravel 5.4 Higher Order Messaging

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Question: Why do the old approach returns the right value see result old approach and the new HOM approach returns the whole collection?

**Role Model**

```
class Role extends Model {
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$roles = Role::all(); // get all roles to test

// old approach
$roles->each(function(Role $i) {
    var_dump($i->getName()); 
});

// new approach (HOM)
var_dump($roles->each->getName());
```

If I implement the new approach with higher order messaging it returns me the whole Collection, if I use the old one I get the right result.

**Result old approach**

> string(11) "Application"
>
> string(6) "System"
>
> string(7) "Network"
>
> string(7) "Manager"

**Result new approach**

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#196 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(4) {
[0]=>
object(App\Modules\Role\Role)#197 (24) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["table":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["keyType":protected]=>
  string(3) "int"
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Application"
    ["description"]=>
    string(91) "Voluptatem similique pariatur iure. Et quaerat possimus laborum non sint aspernatur fugiat."
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-03-03 11:56:09"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-03-03 11:56:09"
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Application"
    ["description"]=>
    string(91) "Voluptatem similique pariatur iure. Et quaerat possimus laborum non sint aspernatur fugiat."
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-03-03 11:56:09"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-03-03 11:56:09"
  }
  ["casts":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dateFormat":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["events":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
}
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each` just iterates over the collection, it doesn't actually return anything. If you want it to return the value of `getName()` for each iteration then you could use map e.g.

```
dump($roles->map->getName());
```

Hope this helps!